# NHibernate and Spring.NET Combination really helpful in the enterprise level application!

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

What are the opinions of the software developers who have used Spring.NET and NHibernate in their projects? In couple of our projects in the company where I work, we have used these third party tools very extensively and we have gained tremendous productivity. A little caveat is that it is a little challenging for junior .Net Developer to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Imo, Spring.Net and NHibernate go hand in hand: If you master the learning curve you will be very pleased when Spring is used for (almost transparent) [transaction handling](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) for NHibernate, Dependency Injection as well as Db:Provider handling.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate (or similar ORM's) can be extremely helpful with "greenfield" development, where the domain object model can be designed properly, and then the database schema and NHibernate mappings can be code-generated to match the model.  On the other hand, NHibernate can be very tough to apply to a legacy or poorly normalized database.  Although it has support for handling some unusual data structures, the learning curve is much higher for those techniques.

I can't say much about Spring.Net except that in 2007, our team tried to implement it into an existing, complex solution to handle DB transactions and entity validation, but we scrapped the idea after a week of work.  Our resident Spring/Java expert concluded that Spring.Net was a couple versions behind Spring and wasn't mature enough to handle the use cases in our project.  Disclaimer: not sure what version of Spring.Net that was, so things may have improved recently.

Answer (score 1):

There has lot of benefits using spring.net/nHibernate.

For data access you are able to take full advantage of nHibernate ORM with lazy loading, database independent programming, easy save load update delete your entities. No need to write any query to do that. That is why after designing a database and after development if  any change is required at any state of development it is very much easy to change.

Dependency Injection(DI) helps to separate the UI and business logic. That is why any time you are able to change your graphical user interface without breaking any business logic. Same way if you need any change at business logic then need only build business layer. And it is also configurable.

Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) is another feature of Spring.Net. It helps logging application, dynamic method interception allow more control over method call. It makes easy to authorize application. Declarative transaction management is a nice feature to manage transactions. You do not need to write code for start stop database connection. Just write at configuration file at which method you want to maintain transaction. So at large scale project it will save lot of time and will give you more flexibility over transaction management.

Spring webservice is very easy to write and consume from a client. Not need to add any custom attribute, no WSDL. You can intercept every method call, you are able to add advice like logging advice, authentication/authorization advice.

Overall it save approximately 33% of development time, make application more maintainable, highly configurable.